# increasing stack reserve size doesn't prevent stack overflow

Tags: c++, stack, stack-overflow

I would like to use a large array on the stack. However I keep on getting stack overflow although I changed the stack reserve size.
For example:

```
int main()
{
    int a[5000000];
    return 0;
}
```

and in visual studio 2012: `Properties -> Linker -> System -> Stack reserve size: 10000000`

What could cause it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of an `int` is probably 4 bytes, so the array is larger in bytes than in the number of elements. `sizeof(int)*5000000` is what you need. (at least)

Comment: Yeah, that's the reason... This is weird because I tried previously to do this and I noticed that adding 1 to the stack reserve size lets me define one more int (= size of DWORD on my computer): I put in the stack reserve size 0 and it let me do an array of ints of size 62200, and when I put there 1 it let me define an array of size 62201..